# If one vertical arrow in a pullback is an iso, then so is the other

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, pullback

Consider the pullback square:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    A @>f>> B\\
    @Vg VV @VV h V\\
    C @>>j > D
\end{CD}

Suppose $h$ is an isomorphism. I'm trying to show that $g$ is an isomorphism. I considered arrows $1_C,h^{-1}\circ j:C\to C$ and defined $\alpha:C\to A$ as the unique map that makes the appropriate triangles commute. In particular that gave $g\circ \alpha=1_C$. But how to prove that $\alpha\circ g = 1_A$? The best I got is $f\circ \alpha\circ g = f$. I don't know how to get rid of $f$.

Comment: Is this just a commutative diagram or a true pullback in the categoric sense? Also, are these general objects and morphisms or do you have a specific category such as R-mod or Grp?

Comment: @mathematics2x2life A true pullback in the categoric sense (otherwise I wouldn't be able to define $\alpha$, I guess). I don't mean any specific category, it's supposed to be a general statement.

Comment: Both answers are very good. I would like to highlight that they each bring something to the table. Chessanator's answer shows you how to prove things about a given pullback (or a given limit in general): if you want to prove that two morphisms with codomain that limit are the same, you prove that they make the same diagram commute. On the other hand, mathematics2x2life's answer teaches something different: if you want to show that a limit has a certain property (here, being isomorphic to $C$), take an object that has this property (here $C$) and show it satisfies the same limit property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can show that $\alpha \circ g$ is equal to $1_A$ using the uniqueness condition for maps into a pullback.

$f:A \rightarrow B$ and $g: A \rightarrow C$ are maps such that $h \circ f = j \circ g$ so there is a unique $x:A \rightarrow A$ such that $f \circ x = f$ and $g \circ x = g$. Obviously, $1_A$ is one such $x$.

We need to show that $(\alpha \circ g)$ is another such map. You've proved that $f \circ (\alpha \circ g) = f$. You can also show that $g \circ (\alpha \circ g) = g$. So $(\alpha \circ g)$ satisfies the condition.

Since there is a unique map $x$ satisfying $f \circ x = f$ and $g \circ x = g$, and both $1_A$ and $(\alpha \circ g)$ satisfy this, they must be equal.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT.** Show that $A=C$ with the proper map; that is, you have

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    C @>h^{-1} \circ j>> B\\
    @V1_C VV @VV h V\\
    C @>>j > D
\end{CD}

This amounts to showing that this diagram has all the desired properties. Note that this shows that isomorphisms always have a pullback (in any category where the pullback exists).